# Mostrar el código y el nombre de la pista más vendida en el periodo comprendido entre abril de 2010 y enero de 2011

Tags: mysql, sql

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select tr.trackId 'identificador', tr.name 'nombre'
from invoiceline invli, track tr, invoice inv
where tr.trackId = (select tr.trackId
        from invoiceline invli, track tr, invoice inv
        where (invli.TrackId = tr.TrackId and inv.invoiceid = invli.invoiceid) and year(inv.invoicedate) between '2010-01' and '2011-04'
        group by tr.TrackId)
order by tr.trackId;
```

Estas son las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `YEAR` nunca va a coincidir con este formato: `'2010-01'` o con este formato `'2011-04'`.

Lo más lógico sería poner el criterio así:

```
... 

WHERE 
    (YEAR(invoicedate)= 2010) OR 
    (YEAR(invoicedate)= 2011 AND MONTH(invoicedate)<=4)
```

Fechas desde el `2010` hasta el mes `4` del `2011`.